# list of gtk2hs widgets

Tags: list, haskell, gtk2hs

how do I create a List (or whatever. Not a Tuple though) that accepts different instances of some typeclass? 
Specifically, I want to do something like the following:

```
[labelNew (Just "foo"), buttonNewWithLabel "bar"]
```

I don’t care for the syntax-sugar, I just want to pass a list of widgets to a function that will pass them to another function which accepts any widgets.

Right now, the purpose is only to get rid of the line-noise, like that

```
boxPackStart box content1 PackNatural 0
boxPackStart box content2 PackNatural 0
...
boxPackStart box content100 PackNatural 0
```

should be eg

```
box <- col PackNatural [content1, content2, ..., content100]
```

I found some pages mentioning some dynamic lists but stopped reading when it said "not typesafe"

Comment: What's the problem with just using an ordinary list of [`Widget`s](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk3-0.14.6/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Abstract-Widget.html#t:Widget)?

Comment: something like the following? `map (\c -> boxPackStart box c PackNatural 0) [content1, content2, content3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For widgets specifically, you can use

```
toWidget :: WidgetClass o => o -> Widget
```

to safely upcast labels and buttons to widgets, as in:

```
do
    label <- labelNew (Just "foo")
    button <- buttonNewWithLabel "bar"
    col PackNatural [toWidget label, toWidget button]
```

Other gtk2hs classes have similar casting functions; generally in that package collection, `to*` is a safe upcast and `castTo*` is an unsafe downcast.